# Unable to generate pdf using wicked gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wicked-pdf

I tried using

```
render pdf: "users/user_information"
```

But I am unable to render it. I looked into the documentation as well but all in vain. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pdf: you have to mention the file name you want it to have on downloading.

`format.pdf do
  render pdf: "file_name"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
 end`

[Documentation - Basic Usage](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#basic-usage)

As far as I have understood I guess you're using your own template from the view. You can use this.

```
render pdf: "User_#{@user.id}", template: 'users/user_information', layout: 'application'
```

Layout can be mentioned if you want the layout of the application, otherwise just skip it.

Comment: Thank you. My bad. I just ignored that part in the documentation.

Comment: Can you please guide about adding styling or bootstrap here?

Comment: For that you have to add the documents you are using for pdf layout in the pipeline in asset.rb file.

Comment: Or if you want to use the layout of the application. You must add wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag in the application.html.erb file.